# Difference between a List's Add and Append method?

Tags: c#

Is there a difference between the `.Append()` and the `.Add()` method for lists in C#? I tried searching in Google and in the site but to my surprise no one asked it. My reason for asking is to know if one of the two methods are less performance intensive. I've been using the two methods interchangeably and I didn't see any differences to their function as they both added my object to the end of the list (and this is more or less the description visual studio gives you when you look at the method description).

**Edit:**

Hmmm I didn't think this mattered at first but I noticed I can use Append on an ASP.NET web application when I can't do that on a console application. So I was asking in the context of an ASP.NET Web App.

Comment: The main difference is that Lists don't have an `Append` method AFAIK. Can you give an example of your code?

Comment: @JLRishe I hadn't thought of that. Thanks! I hadn't thought of the inheritance betwen a List and IEnumerable as pointed out by knittl..

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`List<T>` in C# only has the [`void Add(T item)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Add__0_) to add a single item to the list by modifying the instance.

[`IEnumerable<T> Append(this IEnumerable<T> source, T element)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=netframework-4.7.2) on the other hand is an extension method defined on the `IEnumerable<T>` interface (which is implemented by all lists). It does not modify the original list instance, but returns a new enumerable which will yield the specified element at the end of the sequence.

They cannot be used interchangably and behave differently with different outcomes and different side effects. Asking about their relative performance does not make sense as such.

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add("one");
list.Add("two");
// list contains: [ one, two ]

var appended = list.Append("three");
// list still contains: [ one, two ]
appended.ToList(); // appended will yield [ one, two, three ]
```

Comment: Weird.. okay so the reason I asked this was in the context of ASP.NET. idk if I should have mentioned that part or not but creating a list there allowed me to append to an empty List there which apparently on a console app in C# won't allow me to use the same method (`Append`).

Comment: @kobowo In order to use the Linq extensions (such as `Append`), you'll typically need to have a `using System.Linq;` in the file where you intend to use them. I suspect that's why you're seeing supposed inconsistencies in `Append`s availability. You should be able to use it in both console apps and ASP.NET just fine.

Comment: @JLRishe I tried adding the line but it didn't allow me to use `Append` on my console app.. I make it a habit to always use the `ctrl + .` functionality in vs to check if I'm missing a using statement so yeah...

Comment: @kobowo Looks like it's only available in newer versions of .NET. What version of .NET is your console app using?

Comment: @JLRishe .NET 4.5 if I'm not mistaken? But anyway it's not really a problem with my project...I honestly asked this out of pure curiosity. If it works in newer versions then I'll take note of it. Anyways thanks! my curiosity was sated with everyone's answer :)

Comment: @kobowo `.Append` is included from .NET Framework 4.7.1 onward.

Comment: I disagree about the performance statement.  While the semantics are slightly different, they can be used to achieve the same goal with minor differences in the approach. Many entry/mid level devs certainly use(or misuse) IEnumerable extension methods like .Append and simply assign the resulting referencing of the new list(this is the pattern immutable string modification methods follow like .Substring, so they are somewhat conditioned for it).  In many cases .Add would achieve the same goal and the performance will be orders of magnitude better.

Answer (score 29):

`Add` does not return a value: it modifies the original `List`.

`Append` creates and returns a *new* sequence, so you can:

```
var x = new List<int>();
x.Add(1);
x = x.Append(2).Append(3).ToList();
```

You might like to see [Wikipedia:Fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) for further information on how chaining functions works.

Comment: much clear and easy to understand. `Add` modifies original data while Append returns new array without modifying original data

Comment: @BenVoigt I removed any mention of void to keep it simple. If people like the other, more detailed answer, they can upvote that one instead.