# What is the difference of this, object.Method(); and Method(object);?

Tags: c#, oop

This is an extension method but I am confuse with the difference of the two dot operator.

```
 public static int WordCount(this string str)
        {
            int count = str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?', '!' },
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
            return count;
        }


string str = "Hello, How are you?";
Console.WriteLine(str.WordCount());
Console.WriteLine(ExtensionMethods.WordCount(str));
```

Comment: Technically, there is no difference. The compiler turns `str.WordCount()` into `ExtensionMethods.WordCount(str)`. It's just more convenient to call extension methods using the first syntax, e.g. `something.Where(...).Select(...).ToList()` rather than `Enumerable.ToList(Enumerable.Select(Enumerable.Where(something, ...), ...))`

Comment: good tutorials [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) [best practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/extension-methods#:~:text=Extension%20methods%20are%20a%20language%20feature%20that%20allows,class%2C%20and%20it%20must%20be%20declared%20as%20static.)

Comment: Let me recommend not to use too many extension methods. If you need WordCount in your business logic, then have WordCount as part of your business logic. When I would join your project as a new developer, I would never search for methods on the `string` datatype, because I only expect it to have the methods that Microsoft defined.

Comment: In particular, avoid defining extension methods on primitive types.

Comment: a typical example of side effect of extension method: misunderstandings. [Difference between a List's Add and Append method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52355682/difference-between-a-lists-add-and-append-method)

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods is nice feature of C# that were developed to allow to add features to classes you cannot modify or inherit from.

Extension method is a static method. CLR does not create any special IL code for extension method.

[As General Guidelines of C# Programming Guide says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods#general-guidelines): (special thanks to [Lei Yang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1518100/lei-yang))

> While it's still considered preferable to add functionality by
> modifying an object's code or deriving a new type whenever it's
> reasonable and possible to do so, extension methods have become a
> crucial option for creating reusable functionality throughout the .NET
> ecosystem. **For those occasions when the original source isn't under
> your control, when a derived object is inappropriate or impossible, or
> when the functionality shouldn't be exposed beyond its applicable
> scope, Extension methods are an excellent choice.**
>
> When using an extension method to extend a type whose source code you aren't in
> control of, you run the risk that a change in the implementation of
> the type will cause your extension method to break.
>
> If you do implement extension methods for a given type, remember the
> following points:
>
> An extension method will never be called if it has the same signature
> as a method defined in the type. Extension methods are brought into
> scope at the namespace level. For example, if you have multiple static
> classes that contain extension methods in a single namespace named
> Extensions, they'll all be brought into scope by the using Extensions;
> directive.