# How can I use the ASP.NET [Range] annotation for IEnumerable elements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, annotations

I want to use the ASP.NET `[Range]` Annotation but for the elements `IEnumerable`s.

I used the existing `RangeAttribute` like this:

```cs
public class RangeEnumerable : RangeAttribute
{
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public RangeEnumerable(double minimum, double maximum) : base(minimum, maximum)
    {
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public RangeEnumerable(int minimum, int maximum) : base(minimum, maximum)
    {
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public RangeEnumerable([DynamicallyAccessedMembers((DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes)(-1))] Type type, string minimum, string maximum) : base(type, minimum, maximum)
    {
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public override bool IsValid(object? value)
    {
        if (null == value) { return true; } 

        IEnumerable<object> list = ((IEnumerable)value).Cast<object>();
        
        foreach (object item in list)
        {
            if (!base.IsValid(item))
            {
                return false;
            }                
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

and annotated my Parameter like this:

```cs
[RangeEnumerable(MINIMUM_ANGLE, MAXIMUM_ANGLE)]
public IEnumerable<Double> PhaseAnglesVoltage { get; set; } = new List<double>();
```

And wrote the following unit test:

```cs
[Test]
public void TestInvalidPhaseAngleVoltageTooLow()
{
    // Arrange       
    Loadpoint loadpoint1 = new Loadpoint();
    loadpoint1.PhaseAnglesVoltage.Append(-1);

    // Act
    var errCount = ValidateObject(loadpoint1);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(1, errCount);
}

private int ValidateObject(object obj)
{
    var validationContext = new ValidationContext(obj, null, null);
    var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
    Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, validationContext, validationResults, true);
    return validationResults.Count;
}
```

I expected the loop to iterate over the elements of the List I used the annotation with, but in the `IsValid`-Function I always get an empty List instead of one with the element appended in the test.

Comment: I wouldn't use an `IEnumerable<T>` here anyway. That is just a contract that means "this is something you can iterate over" but it could theoretically contain a never-ending sequence of values. Why not just go with `ICollection<T>` or `List<T>`?

Comment: Because `ICollection.Cast` does not exist and `List` would need an type argument I dont know here, if I'm correct (maybe I just don't know how to use it here correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the error, which was in the unit test. `IEnumerable.Append` doesn't add the element to the original object like `List.Add` does (see [Difference between a List's Add and Append method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52355682/difference-between-a-lists-add-and-append-method)).

Changing the unit test to the following does the trick.

```
        [Test]
        public void TestInvalidPhaseAngleVoltageTooLow()
        {
            // Arrange       
            Loadpoint loadpoint1 = new Loadpoint();
            loadpoint1.PhaseAnglesVoltage = loadpoint1.PhaseAnglesVoltage.Append(-1);

            // Act
            var errCount = ValidateObject(loadpoint1);
   
            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(1, errCount);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created one console app based on your code.

[image]

on line no 8 as you can see and as you said it does not change the source. But after modifying to below line will create another object from that yielded IEnumerable

```
model.Doubles = model.Doubles.Append(1.1).toList();
```

[image]

I think the change you made is not working as expected. You need to do toList() or assign IEnumerable with new List() and then use Add() method of List which will change the source.